# Ubuntu 13.04 - Unable to install JDK7

Tags: 13.04, software-installation, java, jdk

I have an Ubuntu 13.04 64-bit installed and I would like to install JDK 7 for Oracle Sql Developer. My problem is when I try to install it I get the next:

```
kwarr@kwarr-K54LY:~$ sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  visualvm ttf-kochi-gothic ttf-sazanami-gothic ttf-kochi-mincho
  ttf-sazanami-mincho ttf-arphic-uming
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  oracle-java7-installer
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/17,6 kB of archives.
After this operation, 110 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package oracle-java7-installer.
(Reading database ... 200447 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking oracle-java7-installer (from .../oracle-java7-installer_7u51-0~webupd8~1_all.deb) ...
oracle-license-v1-1 license has already been accepted
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info ...
Setting up oracle-java7-installer (7u51-0~webupd8~1) ...
Downloading Oracle Java 7...
--2014-03-22 15:18:09--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u51-b13/jdk-7u51-linux-x64.tar.gz
Resolving download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)... 77.109.171.147, 77.109.171.160
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|77.109.171.147|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u51-b13/jdk-7u51-linux-x64.tar.gz [following]
--2014-03-22 15:18:10--  https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u51-b13/jdk-7u51-linux-x64.tar.gz
Resolving edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)... 23.54.22.140
Connecting to edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)|23.54.22.140|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: http://download.oracle.com/errors/download-fail-1505220.html [following]
--2014-03-22 15:18:10--  http://download.oracle.com/errors/download-fail-1505220.html
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|77.109.171.147|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK

    The file is already fully retrieved; nothing to do.

Download done.
Removing outdated cached downloads...
sha256sum mismatch jdk-7u51-linux-x64.tar.gz
Oracle JDK 7 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing oracle-java7-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java7-installer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have already searched the internet and find some solution that worked for people:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/oracle-java7-installer*
sudo apt-get purge oracle-java7-installer*
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*java*
sudo apt-get update
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

and

```
sudo dpkg -P oracle-java7-installer
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

but none of them worked for me. Still get the same message. Could someone help me with this?

Comment: It's not a problem on your side, but a change on Oracle's side. Instead of the tarball being downloaded an error page is being downloaded that says that you have to agree to the license terms. This doesn't work so well for an automated download.

Comment: You can try using the `openjdk7`

Comment: I installed openjdk7 and it works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Please follow below steps to install oracle java:

- Download the latest Java SE SDK version.

  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html
- Untar the Archive:

  ```
  tar -xzvf /root/jdk-7u17-linux-x64.tar.gz
  mv jdk1.7.0_17 /opt
  cd /opt/jdk1.7.0_17
  ```
- This step registers the downloaded version of Java as an alternative, and switches it to be used as the default:

  ```
  update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /opt/jdk1.7.0_17/bin/java 1
  update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /opt/jdk1.7.0_17/bin/javac 1
  update-alternatives --install /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/libjavaplugin.so mozilla-javaplugin.so /opt/jdk1.7.0_17/jre/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so 1
  update-alternatives --set java /opt/jdk1.7.0_17/bin/java
  update-alternatives --set javac /opt/jdk1.7.0_17/bin/javac
  update-alternatives --set mozilla-javaplugin.so /opt/jdk1.7.0_17/jre/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so
  ```
- Test

  To check the version of Java you are now running

  ```
  java -version
  ```

  To check the browser plugin browse to http://www.java.com/ and click “Do I have Java?”